# SVG icons got blur on Big Size Like tablet

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am using this icon in the react native and works fine but these got blur on big size screen

```
export const IconToShow = props => {
  let {  width = 14, height = 14 } = props;
  return (
    <Svg
      id="file_download_done_black_24dp"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={width}
      height={height}
      viewBox="0 0 14 14"
      {...props}>
      <G id="Group_16067" data-name="Group 16067">
        <Rect
          id="Rectangle_2853"
          data-name="Rectangle 2853"
          width={14}
          height={14}
          fill="none"
        />
      </G>
      <G
        id="Group_16069"
        data-name="Group 16069"
        transform="translate(2.257 2.333)">
        <G id="Group_16068" data-name="Group 16068">
          <Path
            id="Path_6906"
            data-name="Path 6906"
            d="M13.355,4.822,12.532,4,7.172,9.361,4.693,6.887,3.87,7.71l3.3,3.3Z"
            transform="translate(-3.87 -4)"
            fill={'red'}
          />
          <Rect
            id="Rectangle_2854"
            data-name="Rectangle 2854"
            width={8.167}
            height={1.167}
            transform="translate(0.659 8.167)"
            fill={'red'}
          />
        </G>
      </G>
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

When i increase screen size it got blur as as svg icons take resolution accoding to screen not getting why is this happens